# How to make custom code in python utilize GPU while using Pytorch tensors and matrice functions

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, conv-neural-network

I've created a CNN from scratch only using Pytorch tensors and matrix operation functions in the hope of utilizing GPU. To my surprise, the GPU stays 0% utilized and my training doesn't seem to be faster than running on my cpu.

**Before Training:**

[image]
[image]

**While Training:**

[image]
[image]

I've double checked whether CUDA is available and have installed it already.

Graphics card: Nvidia GEFORCE 2070 SUPER

Processor: Intel i5 10400

Coding Environment: Jupyter Notebook

Cuda & Cudnn Version: 11.0

Pytorch version: 1.6.0

Comment: Once check command `nvidia-smi` inside another terminal while running the code. May be your code utilizing too less GPU. Usage of `nvidia-smi` is better to check GPU usage of DL models

Comment: I don't see my GPU being used after running the command you said. I've added the command result in my question above, please review.

Comment: in GPU utlilization graph, there is written 3D, it means graph is shown just of 3D usage not of CUDA, there is a downward arrow with 3d use that to change it to CUDA and you will be able to see the cuda usage.

Comment: @Mughees Yeah, now I can see the cuda usage and it's around 27% while training. Thanks for pointing that out. But I was training with batch size of 1000, how could it use only 27% of the cuda cores? And it takes almost an hour or so to compute the forward and backward propagation of one batch.

Comment: In your code, all the classes are on the CPU thats why there are using CPU. Pytorch implemets the GPU utilization from backend. and `.cuda` will work when the class is inheriting the `torch.nn.Module` class.

Comment: @Mugheess Oh you're right! But I was already inheriting the Module class which I made, is it possible to inherit from Pytorch's Module function together with my Module function?

Comment: I meant, the Module 'class'.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try to inherit the torch.nn.module at your module class.

Comment: Also you can take up this case at pytorch discussion form as well. As that's a dedicated ecosystem for pytorch.and you will be able to talk to the developers of pytorch about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your model and data to GPU using

```
model.cuda()
# and 
x = x.cuda()
y = y.cuda()
```

You seem to be doing this with-in the calls of forward and backwards. To make sure the model is going on to GPU, monitor the GPU usage continually using shell command

`watch -n 5 nvidia-smi`

Comment: I've added the result of running the 'nvidia-smi' command in my question above. And i can't do model.cuda() as I've created model from scratch and not using it from Pytorch. I've used only the tensors and matrice functions from Pytorch. Other than that it's a simple python code.

Comment: since you are moving your tensors to cuda and since it is running without failure it must be going to GPU. Can you take a screenshot of the output of `nvidia-smi` before running the training and the one more after running the training. During training wait for one epoch to finish and then take the screenstop.

Comment: Added the screenshots above in the question. It seems like the load is on the cpu rather on gpu.